# Can I use two 2x8 beams instead of one 4x8 beam for deck?

Tags: deck, lumber, beam

I am trying to "optimize" materials purchase when building a deck. So I have two questions:

1. Is two 2x8x16 beams the same as one 4x8x16 beam for deck support? Do I need to bolt / nail them together or just sit them side by side on top of the posts?
2. `<question about pricing removed since it's off topic>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pair the beams up, you should glue them with construction adhesive. Just nailing or screwing them together won't really distribute the load across both beams. Although; you're probably not planning on hanging or resting anything on just one beam and expecting the other beam to help with the load anyway.

**A pair of 2x8 beams are going to be 3" wide** (typically 1/4" is planed off each side of dimensioned lumber to give it the finished surface).

**A 4x8 beam is going to be 3-1/2" wide**. The extra half inch is going to add some strength to the 4x8 beam.

The 4x8 might be more prone to warping than a couple of 2x8's if it's a solid beam (but not if it's a laminated beam).

If this was for indoor use, you could sandwich a strip of plywood between the 2x8 beams and glue (not nail) all three pieces together to create a laminated beam that would be stronger and less prone to warping than the 4x8. But since you're building a deck, the sandwiched plywood would soak up water and be a problem.

Comment: This is a good answer. Look like I will not use two 2x8 then because I do plan to use the joist hangers on both sides. Plus, dealing with adhesive gonna take more time than pay additional $10 for one 4x8 ;-) Just thinking out loud

Comment: Nowadays they don't actually plane 1/4" off each side of dimensional lumber.  They cut it much closer than that.  That's one reason the thicker boards cost more, they require more timber to make.

Comment: Sure. Tomato/Tamawto, though. The net result either way is that a "2 by" piece of lumber is 1-1/2" wide, so two "2 by" pieces of lumber together will be 3" wide, and a "4 by" piece of lumber will be 3-1/2" wide.

Answer (score 0):

2 2x8 12% stronger than 4x8 beam if those are true dimensions, but, 2 2x8 = 3x7.5, and 4x8 = 3.5x7.5 (22% bigger)....beam wins by 7%. (look out for warping)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this needs a reference